# Resizing components in an image when image was resizing in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an Image in that I need to place some `textboxes` and `checkboxes` in the Image but when I try  to resize the image in a `picturebox`, how to resize all the components that was placed in the Image ?

For this I used Windows Form

1.adding `picturebox` and placing the components in that `picturebox`

Sample code I used was :

```
 Metafile EMF = (System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile)System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile.FromFile("Sample.EMF");
 this.pictureBox1.Image = EMF;     
 pictureBox1.Controls.Add(textBox1);    
 this.textBox1.Parent = this.imageBox;  
 textBox1.BringToFront();
```

With this code I was able to fix the components' position in the image but when the image was resized , how can I resize all the components that are placed in the image.

Comment: Set the [Control.Anchor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.anchor?view=netcore-3.1) property to `AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right` to resize a control horizontally, or/and `AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom` to resize it vertically. Better to use a [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel?view=netcore-3.1) to manage the layout. Also you should know that the `PictureBox` is not a container control, so it shouldn't be used as one.

Comment: Graphics.ScaleTransform() to rescale a metafile.  PictureBox just doesn't help you do this, instead of the Image property you must write your own Paint event handler.

Comment: Rescaling the metafile was good but my problem was i need to show components on metafile and whenever the form that contain the metafile was resized i need to resize the metafile as well as the components showed  on metafile.my Application have an UI like that How can i show components on metafile particular location & fixing that position for the components and changing the height and width when the metafile was zooming and out. Any suggestions to implement it. Thanks in Advance